# Error while trying to build ember js project

Tags: javascript, node.js, ember.js, ember-cli, build-error

whenever i build my ember project with outputPath=dist and environment=production it build fine but when i build with outputPath=dist-something and environment=hosted-something then i get the below error:

```
Build failed.
Invalid mapping: {"generated":{"line":74176,"column":-50},**"source":"bower_components/moment/min/moment.min.js"**,"original
":{"line":1,"column":0},"name":null}
Error: Invalid mapping: {"generated":{"line":74176,"column":-50},"source":"bower_components/moment/min/moment.min.js","o
riginal":{"line":1,"column":0},"name":null}
    at SourceMapGenerator_validateMapping [as _validateMapping] (C:\wamp\www\PublicMD\EmberMD\Ta\trunk\TextAdminLatestEm
ber\node_modules\ember-cli-uglify\node_modules\broccoli-uglify-sourcemap\node_modules\uglify-js\node_modules\source-map\
lib\source-map\source-map-generator.js:272:15)
    at SourceMapGenerator_addMapping [as addMapping] (C:\wamp\www\PublicMD\EmberMD\Ta\trunk\TextAdminLatestEmber\node_mo
dules\ember-cli-uglify\node_modules\broccoli-uglify-sourcemap\node_modules\uglify-js\node_modules\source-map\lib\source-
map\source-map-generator.js:102:12)
    at C:\wamp\www\PublicMD\EmberMD\Ta\trunk\TextAdminLatestEmber\node_modules\ember-cli-uglify\node_modules\broccoli-ug
lify-sourcemap\node_modules\uglify-js\node_modules\source-map\lib\source-map\source-map-generator.js:74:19
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at SourceMapConsumer_eachMapping [as eachMapping] (C:\wamp\www\PublicMD\EmberMD\Ta\trunk\TextAdminLatestEmber\node_m
odules\ember-cli-uglify\node_modules\broccoli-uglify-sourcemap\node_modules\uglify-js\node_modules\source-map\lib\source
-map\source-map-consumer.js:473:10)
    at Function.SourceMapGenerator_fromSourceMap [as fromSourceMap] (C:\wamp\www\PublicMD\EmberMD\Ta\trunk\TextAdminLate
stEmber\node_modules\ember-cli-uglify\node_modules\broccoli-uglify-sourcemap\node_modules\uglify-js\node_modules\source-
map\lib\source-map\source-map-generator.js:50:26)
    at Context.SourceMap (C:\wamp\www\PublicMD\EmberMD\Ta\trunk\TextAdminLatestEmber\node_modules\ember-cli-uglify\node_
modules\broccoli-uglify-sourcemap\node_modules\uglify-js\lib\sourcemap.js:59:52)
    at Object.exports.minify (C:\wamp\www\PublicMD\EmberMD\Ta\trunk\TextAdminLatestEmber\node_modules\ember-cli-uglify\n
ode_modules\broccoli-uglify-sourcemap\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:112:38)
    at UglifyWriter.processFile (C:\wamp\www\PublicMD\EmberMD\Ta\trunk\TextAdminLatestEmber\node_modules\ember-cli-uglif
y\node_modules\broccoli-uglify-sourcemap\index.js:98:25)
    at C:\wamp\www\PublicMD\EmberMD\Ta\trunk\TextAdminLatestEmber\node_modules\ember-cli-uglify\node_modules\broccoli-ug
lify-sourcemap\index.js:46:14
```

would be great if somebody can let me know what the reason could be and also the solution

It seems to be a error when brocfile.js is being parsed by uglifyJs. Since currently in brcofile.js i use the below lines

```
app.import('bower_components/moment/min/moment.min.js');
app.import('bower_components/jquery-file-upload/js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js');
app.import('bower_components/jquery-file-upload/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js');
app.import('bower_components/jquery-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload.js');
```

However when i use the below order,

```
app.import('bower_components/jquery-file-upload/js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js');
app.import('bower_components/jquery-file-upload/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js');
app.import('bower_components/jquery-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload.js');
app.import('bower_components/moment/min/moment.min.js');
```

the error becomes

> Build failed. Invalid mapping:
>   {"generated":{"line":74174,"column":-50},"source":"bower_components/jquery-file-upload/js/vendor/jquery
>   .ui.widget.js","original":{"line":1,"column":0},"name":null} Error:
>   Invalid mapping:
>   {"generated":{"line":74174,"column":-50},**"source":"bower_components/jquery-file-upload/js/vendor
>   /jquery.ui.widget.js"**,"original":{"line":1,"column":0},"name":null}
>       at SourceMapGenerator_validateMapping [as _validateMapping] (C:\wamp\www\PublicMD\EmberMD\Ta\trunk\TextAdminLatestEm
>   ber\node_modules\ember-cli-uglify\node_modules\broccoli-uglify-sourcemap\node_modules\uglify-js\node_modules\source-map\
>   lib\source-map\source-map-generator.js:272:15)

*********Update with entire borcfile as per comment suggestion******

```
var EmberApp = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app');


var isProduction = ['production', 'hosted-something'].indexOf(process.env.EMBER_ENV) > -1;

var app = new EmberApp({

    fingerprint: {
        enabled: false
    },

    hinting: !isProduction,

    minifyCSS: {
        enabled: isProduction
    },

    minifyJS: {
        enabled: isProduction
    },

    storeConfigInMeta: false,

    tests: !isProduction,

    vendorFiles: {        
        'jquery.js': 'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',

        'handlebars.js': null,

        'ember.js': {
            'hosted-something':  'bower_components/ember/ember.prod.js'
        },

    },

    wrapInEval: !isProduction
});

if (app.env !== 'hosted-something') {
    app.import('bower_components/bootstrap-go/index.css');
    app.import('bower_components/bootstrap-go-responsive/index.css');
}

app.import('bower_components/moment/min/moment.min.js');
app.import('bower_components/jquery-file-upload/js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js');
app.import('bower_components/jquery-file-upload/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js');
app.import('bower_components/jquery-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload.js');

module.exports = app.toTree();
```

Comment: lol seriously??? btw this started happening all of a sudden without any change to node_modules or anything!

Comment: Consider asking about this on the ember-cli tracker: https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues the maintainers are really helpful and this does look like a bug

Comment: Are you using the [ember-cli-jquery-ui](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-cli-jquery-ui) ?

Comment: Can you post your entire `Brocfile.js` so we can see what else you're doing for your build? I had this same problem and found a fix, but want to make sure the source of your problem is the same as mine.

Comment: @BasementKeyboardHero yes "bower_components/jquery-file-upload/js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js"

Comment: @awgreenarrow08 sure, i ve updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to your brocfile:

```
sourcemaps: {
  enabled: !isProduction
}
```

The error you are getting is due to the build attempting to generate sourcemaps while you are running a "production" build.

Comment: awesome boss thanks a lot : )
i never realised sourcemaps was not there : )